# Failed: Required Request Body is missing: public springframework.http.ResponseEntity...postController

Tags: java, angular, hibernate, spring-boot

I have created to applications based examples from Web: Frontend in Angular and Backend with Spring Boot
    mer customer)
    Angular URL: http://localhost:4200/
    Spring Boot URL: http://localhost:9020/ (REST: http://localhost:9020/api/)

```
<h1>Angular Part </h1>

`export class Customer {
    id: number;
    firstname: number;
    lastname: Number;
    age: number;
    active: boolean;}`
```

## And

```
import { Customer } from './customer';
    export class CustomerService {
      private baseUrl = http://localhost:9020/api';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

     getCustomer(id: number): Observable<Object> {
        return this.http.get(${this.baseUrl}+`/customers`+/${id});}

      createCustomer(customer: Customer): Observable<Object> {
        console.log("customer.lastname: "+customer.lastname);
        console.log("customer.firstname: "+customer.firstname);
        return this.http.post(${this.baseUrl} + `/create`, customer);
      }
      getCustomersList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(${this.baseUrl}+`/customers`);
      }
    }


    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Customer } from '../customer';
    import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';`

    @Component({
      selector: 'create-customer',
      templateUrl: './create-customer.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./create-customer.component.css']
    })

    export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
      customer: Customer = new Customer();
      submitted = false;
      constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
      }

      newCustomer(): void {
        this.submitted = false;
        this.customer = new Customer();
      }

      save() {
        this.customerService.createCustomer(this.customer)
          .subscribe(data => {console.log(data);
            this.submitted = true;},error => console.log(error));
            this.customer = new Customer();}

      onSubmit() {   
        this.save();}}
```

## Spring Boot

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "last_Name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "first_Name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active = true;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, int age, boolean active) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.active=active;
}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerController {

  @Autowired
  CustomerRepository repository;


  @PostMapping(value = "/create")
  public ResponseEntity<Customer> postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    try {
      Customer _customer = repository.save(new Customer(customer.getFirstName(),customer.getLastName(),customer.getAge(),customer.isActive()));
      return new ResponseEntity<>(_customer, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
    }
  }
}
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
       id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       lastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

**application.properties:**

- server.port=9020
- spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./testdb
- spring.datasource.username=H2 spring.datasource.password=password
- spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
- spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

  Payload{"id":518,"lastName":null,"firstName":null,"age":99,"active":true}
  lastName and firstName should be string values since I enter strings [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s8jH.png)

  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s8jH.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s8jH.png

Comment: What do I wrong here? Obvisiouly the values I enter leads to numberformat exception. Any Idea?

Comment: Look at the error. It tells you exactly what went wrong: spring attempted to convert the string "create" to a Java `long` type. This probably means you are attempting to create a Customer with an id of "create" in your `getCustomer()` function in the second code snippet. Trace the call to this function and ensure that you are passing in a Number type.

Comment: POST: http://localhost:9020/api/create  {
  "active": true,
  "age": 55,
  "firstname": "Test",
  "lastname": "Test"
}  Result  {
    "id": 591,
    "lastName": null,
    "firstName": null,
    "age": 55,
    "active": true
}  Any Idea?

Comment: After changes: I got this error: `Method Create Customer @RequestMapping(value = "/create") public ResponseEntity<Customer> postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<Customer> CustomerController.postCustomer(Customer) org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<Customer> CustomerController.postCustomer(Customer)`Attached my Post abouve

Comment: I need help. Do you any Idea what I am doing here wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Entity class, the column called "first_name", but when you create the table, it is named with "firstname", the underscore disappeared.